# How to preview compose layout when you're getting data from api

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm setting up ui for my Lazy column and I'm getting data from api

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun MatchesRow(data: Data ) {

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(180.dp),
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
}}
```

i get erros because my parameters are empty , how can i Preview ??

Answer (score 1):

you have to create two function, one of which receives the data from the ViewModel, and the other is the case you mentioned

Note : One Stateful and one Stateless

But in order to be able to preview, you must act as follows:

```
@Composable
fun MatchesRow(data: Data ) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(180.dp),
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
}}


@Preview
@Composable
fun MatchesRowPreview() {
val data = .....
 MatchesRow(
   data = data
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preview a composable with a parameter, you can use `@PreviewParameter` annotation.

Say your data class looks like this,

```
data class Data(
    val dataValue: String
)
```

and you have this composable with text inside a red box in the middle of the screen,

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun DataDetails(details: Data) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                text = details.dataValue
            )
        }

    }
}
```

and you want to **preview** it, you have to create a `PreviewParemeterProvider` first,

```
class DataPreviewProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<Data> {
    override val values = listOf(Data(dataValue = "Hello")).asSequence()
}
```

and annotate the parameter with `@PreviewParameter` and pass the DataPreviewProvider to it like this.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun DataDetails(@PreviewParameter(DataPreviewProvider::class) details: Data) {
   ...
}
```

[image]

I would also suggest to just simply create another composable solely for "previewing" purposes.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun DataDetailsPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(DataPreviewProvider::class) dataDetails: Data) {
    DataDetails(userDetailsDisplay)
}
```

You can also check this [@PreviewParemeter](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/general/preview/previewparameter/)

Comment: Hello i tried doing that , i used preview parameter class to insert data in data class for my apis, but I am getting unresolved reference error while building the app, what could be the reason

Comment: where in the code you see the unresolved reference error? do you have these dependencies declared? `debugImplementation androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.0`
`implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.0`

Comment: i the preview parameter provider class i'm getting the error in data class that i imported to put dummy data in , it's giving me unresolved reference error at lines of data class packages i'm importing

Comment: getting the same error after double checking the dependencies

Comment: Oh sorry i fixed it, i just changed val to var in my variables in data class thanks again for help